# Maven: How to check if jar is not uploaded in central repo

Tags: java, maven

How can I be sure that my jar files ARE NOT loaded to central repo maven? I am asking this question as I saw several times exception like - error while uploading to central repo. I was shocked (as I didn't make any configurations in pom and not applied to central repo administration). That's why I decided to ask this question.

So, how can I check that the absence or presence of some code guarantee that my jar is not uploading to central repo?

Comment: First you never upload directly to Maven Central. The first gate is a staging repository. Furthermore it would be interesting which kind of error you get?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which repository your project should be deployed to via the [Distribution Management](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) section of pom.xml. I think there is no default. However, it's possible that you have a parent pom.xml specified and it contains some setting. If that is the case, you can modify parent. Failing that, you can override it by putting your own private repository details in this section to avoid deploying your artifacts anywhere else. It can even be invalid URL, in which case deployment will simply always fail.

Example:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>fake-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://fake/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>fake-releases</id>
        <url>https://fake/releases</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check whether are you using `deploy:deploy-file` goal under `maven-deploy-plugin` in your `POM.xml`.

This feature is used to deploy jar files to the remote repo.

Comment: You shoud never use a `deploy-file` goal in your pom file...simply use `mvn deploy` this will handle all.